# Download file from server container to client container in Docker

Tags: python, docker, python-sockets

I have a program in Python where the client uploads a file to the server and then server sends it back to the client or client downloads it from the server. I want to ultimately achieve this using Docker in an user-defined network.

So, I have containerized the client and server as containers respectively. The issue that is arising is that when I am executing the `docker run` for both of them, it's not showing any result or error, it's just there on the command line like it is stuck or in an infinite loop. I will be attaching the codes and the `docker run` commands that I am using/executing.

What can I do to debug this issue?

Note: This is not my Python program and I don't intend to make it mine too. I found this code somewhere on the internet in a public forum. I am just using it for testing it with Docker (I am a beginner in Docker).

Code for client.py and Dockerfile

```
import socket
 
csFT = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
csFT.connect(("server", 8756))
 
text_file = "/client/send.txt"
 
#Send file
with open(text_file, 'rb') as fs: 
    #Using with, no file close is necessary, 
    #with automatically handles file close
    csFT.send(b'BEGIN')
    while True:
        data = fs.read(1024)
        print('Sending data', data.decode('utf-8'))
        csFT.send(data)
        print('Sent data', data.decode('utf-8'))
        if not data:
            print('Breaking from sending data')
            break
    csFT.send(b'ENDED')
    fs.close()
 
#Receive file
print("Receiving..")
with open(text_file, 'wb') as fw:
    while True:
        data = csFT.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        fw.write(data)
    fw.close()
print("Received..")
 
csFT.close()
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:alpine3.10
COPY client.py /client/
COPY send.txt /client/
WORKDIR /client/
CMD python ./client.py
```

Code for server.py and dockerfile

```
import socket
 
ssFT = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssFT.bind((socket.gethostname(), 8756))
ssFT.listen(1)
while True:
    (conn, address) = ssFT.accept()
    text_file = "/server/fileProj.txt"
 
    #Receive, output and save file
    with open(text_file, "wb") as fw:
        print("Receiving..")
        while True:
            print('receiving')
            data = conn.recv(32)
            if data == b'BEGIN':
                continue
            elif data == b'ENDED':
                print('Breaking from file write')
                break
            else:
                print('Received: ', data.decode('utf-8'))
                fw.write(data)
                print('Wrote to file', data.decode('utf-8'))
        fw.close()
        print("Received..")
 
    #Append and send file
    #print('Opening file ', text_file)
    with open(text_file, 'ab+') as fa:
        print('Opened file')
        print("Appending string to file.")
        string = b"Append this to file."
        fa.write(string)
        fa.seek(0, 0)
        print("Sending file.")
        while True:
            data = fa.read(1024)
            conn.send(data)
            if not data:
                break
        fa.close()
        print("Sent file.")
    break
ssFT.close()
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:alpine3.10
WORKDIR /server/
EXPOSE 8756
COPY server.py /server/
COPY fileProj.txt /server/
CMD python ./server.py
```

The commands that I have been using for executing on the command line are

```
docker network create mynet

docker run --name server -p 8756:8756 --network mynet server:1.0

docker run --name client --network mynet client:1.0
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I'll keep in mind. Btw, can you help me with this program ?

Comment: I assume your `docker run` commands are run in separate consoles, and each produce log output, and the console is blocked in each case (since neither command pushes the container to the background). If that is so, you can probably see the error/issue in the logs. Please add those logs to your question.

Comment: If the server returns control in the same console then there may be a crash of some kind that is stopping it run. Let us know if that is the case.

Comment: Yes, they are run in separate consoles. It is not showing log of any kind. The docker run command is just there not showing anything and, not closing by itself too and I am not using -d too. When I am executing docker logs server and docker logs client in separate consoles, it is not giving anything. I feel, it is related to the python sockets. I don't know

Comment: Try shelling into the client and see if the server is pingable. You can probably do `docker exec -it client sh` to get a console on the client, and from there you can try `ping server`. If Ping is not installed, you may need to install it via `apk add` (I think the package is called `inetutils`).

Comment: (It is not important, but you don't need to publish the port with `-p 8756:8756`, since you are connecting from one container to the other in an internal virtual network. Publishing only affects connecting to a container from a host).

Comment: Will do what you said and will get back to you.

Comment: Why don't you use docker-compose?

Comment: Even if this did work, after the client calls `csFT.close()`, the script ends, causing the container to close, so you wouldn't even be able to access the file that was written inside of it... More importantly, what happens when you run both scripts outside of docker? If something hangs, then that is not necessarily a Docker issue

Comment: @OneCricketeer So, what should I do then ?

Comment: @halfer I did what you proposed. The server is pingable. What should I do next ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you have an issue with your Python, in that case. I would recommend adding more `print` statements to both scripts, particularly before any loops, so you can see the server start up, and so you can see the client doing something. You've mentioned that you haven't seen any output so far, which is why I would dig into getting some output.

Comment: (I second the suggestion to use Docker Compose - you don't have to set up a network with that. However, I don't think Docker is the problem here, so DC probably doesn't buy you anything).

Comment: (When amending the code, don't forget to rebuild the images, so you are running the latest copies).

Comment: @halfer I tried doing what you said and I am still not getting any output. I rebuilt the images and did it.

Comment: Consider trying `CMD ["python", "/client/client.py"]` (and similar for the server). Don't forget to rebuild.

Comment: @halfer From what I observed after doing what you proposed, I felt there is some issue in the client and server in connecting with each other

Comment: I am now out of ideas. If you are still stuck, please don't send "I am helpless" messages. I am very happy to help, but tell your readers what is happening. If you don't give us useful observations, readers can't give you more assistance.

Comment: OK, great. Sounds like a good avenue for research!

Comment: @OneCricketeer you have helped me in the past with a problem little similar to this. According to you, what could be the issue ?

Comment: Make sure the version of Python and the version these programs need is the same - 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: It's the correct version

Comment: I ran your code, and I get the same thing until I Ctrl+C the client. I suspect it works the exact same way outside of Docker, so debug it and see what the problem is... This is to be expected if you grab random code off the internet... My guess is that `conn.recv(32)` is too short, so the two conditions afterwards are never true, and you should print the actual received data to verify that